# How do I set storage engine to MySQL database when designing a model on Enterprise Architect?

Tags: mysql, enterprise-architect

I've been using EA to design my database models, but generated script isn't specifying the storage engine to be used in create table commands. Is there any way to set a default storage engine (for example InnoDB) to be used in ddl script ? I'm using version 7.1.883.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to add a tagged value to achieve this, please check the link below
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/database_engineering/setmysqltabletype.html

Answer (score 1):

you can set a default storage engine for the current session by setting the `storage_engine` variable

e.g

```
Set storage_engine = InnoDB
```

you can also add the below line in my.cnf  in [mysqld] group

`default-storage-engine=innodb`